# Creating an Image in Window using Tkinter

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am creating a Blackjack game using Python Tkinter and trying to get a simple card image on to a canvas in a Window. I have tried everything but still cannot get this to work. I think the problem is getting the path to the file into my code but I copy and pasted it directly from properties of this image.

Below is the code I have used recently:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import random
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
root.title("Blackjack")

canvas = Canvas(root, bg="green", height=1200, width=800)
canvas.create_image(
    600, 400, image=r"C:/Users/dskim/OneDrive/Desktop/GUI/Images/Cards/2_of_clubs.png")
card_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(
    file=r"C:/Users/dskim/OneDrive/Desktop/GUI/Images/Cards/2_of_clubs.png")
canvas.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

And this is the error I keep getting:
_tkinter.TclError: image "C:/Users/dskim/OneDrive/Desktop/GUI/Images/Cards/2_of_clubs.png" doesn't exist

I have tried different path names and also different types of code but still no luck.

Comment: If you're getting that error, then it's almost certain that the file doesn't exist at that path. You must have a typo somewhere.

Comment: You need to move the line `card_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="...")` before `canvas.create_image(...)` and set `image=card_img` instead of the full path of the image.

Answer (score 0):

The `image` option of `.create_image()` expects an instance of `PhotoImage` instead of a full path, so you need to move the line `card_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(...)` before calling `.create_image()`:

```py
card_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="C:/Users/dskim/OneDrive/Desktop/GUI/Images/Cards/2_of_clubs.png")
canvas.create_image(600, 400, image=card_img)
```